# :hover em elemento anterior

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Gostaria de ao dar :hover no botão "2" mundando o efeito no botão "1"

```
<div class="btn um">1</div>
<div class="btn dois">2</div>
<div class="btn tres">3</div>
```

exemplo:

```
.um:hover ~ .dois {} (isto funciona)
.dois:hover ~ .um {} ( porem isto não funciona)
```

gostaria de saber se tem como fazer um efeito hover em um elemento anterior

Comment: Não dá (por enquanto), mas tem na especificação dos "seletores de nível 4" das css. Por hora, só usando Javascript.

Comment: Provavelmente você tenha que usar Jquery, aparentemente pela lógica do seu problema você poderia usar um NG-class do ANGULARJS, sugiro que você de uma pesquisada no angular amigo, ele é de extrema valia, e facilita MUITO. (em vez de ter que ficar usando Jquery), até onde sei aparenta ser possivel sua solicitação pelo ng-class

Comment: Se houver `:hover` no "1" qual deve ter efeito? e se houver `:hover` no "3" qual deve ter efeito?

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível com css apenas. Você pode fazer isso facilmente com jquery veja:

```js
            $(".um").hover(
                function() {$(".dois").addClass('hover-btn-02')},
                function() {$(".dois").removeClass('hover-btn-02')}
            );
            $(".dois").hover(
                function() {$(".um").addClass('hover-btn-01')},
                function() {$(".um").removeClass('hover-btn-01')}
            );
```

```css
a{display: table;padding: 20px;margin:5px;background-color: red;}
.hover-btn-01{background-color: green;}
.hover-btn-02{background-color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn um" href="">01</a>
<a class="btn dois" href="">02</a>
<a class="btn tres" href="">03</a>
```